# clarification on the relationship between binomial and negative binomial probability mass function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I came across this relationship in my notes, and not quite understanding a certain part

Negative Binomial: Y ~ NB (r,p) for r = number of success and p is the probability
of each success

$$ p(k) = p(Y=k) = (^{k-1}_{r-1})p^r(1-p)^{k-r}, r\geq k $$

then

$$Pr(l \leq Y \leq k) = Pr(Y \leq k) - P(Y \leq l-1) = Pr(N_k \geq r) - Pr(N_{l-1} \geq r) $$

where $N_k$ is the number of successes in the first k trials and $N_{l-1}$
the number of successes in the first l-1 trials.

I'm not understanding how theses equate to each other, why is it greater than equal to?

$$Pr(Y \leq k) - P(Y \leq l-1) = Pr(N_k \geq r) - Pr(N_{l-1} \geq r) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ counts the number of trials until $r$ successes.  $N_k$ counts the successes in the first $k$ trials.

$Y\leq k$ is the event of $r$ successes occurring in no more than $k$ trials.

$N_k\geq r$ is the event of $r$ or more successes in the first $k$ trials.

These are the same event, that the $r$-th success does not occur after the $k$-th trial.

So their probabilities had better be equal.

$\therefore\qquad\mathsf P(Y\leq k)-\mathsf P(Y\leq l-1)=\mathsf P(N_k\geq r)-\mathsf P(N_{l-1}\geq r)$

$\blacksquare$